# MySql drivers for .NET doesn't support Polygon struct, does it?

Tags: c#, mysql, serialization, geometry, blob

I'm trying to fetch a `Polygon` data from MySQL into my C# application.

I have exactly defined in one table the `Polygon` field where geodata holds.

**Proof:**

```
SELECT GeometryType(GeomFromText(AsWKT(object))) as `type` FROM geo.data;
```

Returns:

[image]

So the object in the table is fine and correctly defined.

There is a source code in C#:

http://ideone.com/bn1urQ

And the main lines are (73-76):

```
//var polygon = (byte[])reader["object"];
//var obj = new MySqlGeometry(MySqlDbType.Blob, polygon);
var polygon = reader["object"].ToString();
var obj = MySqlGeometry.Parse(polygon);
```

I've commented, but this isn't an obstacle to tell you about both operations:

- retrieving as `BLOB` with the next deserialization
- parsing the fetched string via `MySqlGeometry.Parse(System.String)` method

**BLOB retrieving**

Well, I shall start with commented part of code, let's imagine, that these lines are uncommented and there aren't lines 75 and 76 with string parsing.

Also there is another correction, the SQL query which is sending to the MySQL server must look like:

```
SELECT AsWKB(object) as 'object' FROM geo.data
```

I've just changed in SQL query the function `AsWKT()` to the `AsWKB()` (from text to binary formatter at MySQL).

So, the result of this query would be:

[image]

At lines:

```
var polygon = (byte[])reader["object"];
var obj = new MySqlGeometry(MySqlDbType.Blob, polygon);
```

You are able to see that I'm fetching that `BLOB` object then converting it to the `System.Byte[]` array and only then I'm trying to build the `MySqlGeomerty`, but it's very pity and seems to be that MySQL libraries are identifying this object as a `POINT`, not a `POLYGON`.

**Proof:**

[image]

But!!! I have exactly the `POLYGON` object in MySQL, by the next SQL query:

```
SELECT GeometryType(GeomFromText(AsWKT(object))) as `type`,
                    AsWKT(object) as `data` FROM geo.data
```

**Proof:**

[image]

That was about the `BLOB` object.

**Geometry parsing from System.String**

Now... Let's imagine the original source with commented `BLOB` fetching.

Let's look at the lines:

```
var polygon = reader["object"].ToString();
var obj = MySqlGeometry.Parse(polygon);
```

And shall change the SQL query in the C# app source code to the:

```
SELECT AsWKT(object) as 'object' FROM geo.data
```

Yes... MySQL libraries for .NET are providing allegedly another style of geomerty bulding, from the `System.String`.

But, when I'm trying to parse the `var polygon`, which is retrieving correctly as you have seen above, I'm getting the next error:

```
System.FormatException: String does not contain a valid geometry value
```

**Proof:**

[image]
[image]

All these do look like, that MySQL libraries don't provide a full structures for the data binding from MySQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have asked the similar question at the MySQL official forum, it's here:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,596620,596620

One man from Oracle team... **Roberto Ezequiel Garcia Ballesteros** has answered me that MySQL .NET driver doesn't support such a type of geometry currently:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,596620,596746#msg-596746

> Hi Oleg,
>
> I'm afraid we are supporting only Point and **not** Polygon. I'm sorry for
>   the inconvenience.
>
> Cheers,  Roberto